# How to get .text() to work with .clone() sequentially

Tags: jquery

I've been modifying a snippet for cloning the Customer Profile section of my questionnaire.  at the top of the section I have a div set up as a title which is

```
<div class="sub_title04" id="cus_title">Customer 01</div>
```

the JQuery snippet I'm calling it up in is

```
$("#p20_01_yes").click(function(){
var num = $('.clone_el').length,
newNum = new Number(num + 1),
clonedFieldset = $("#cloner").clone().appendTo("#page20");

clonedFieldset.attr('id',('cloner')+newNum).find("input, textarea, select, label, #cus_title").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);

    item.attr('name', item.attr('name') +newNum).attr('id', item.attr('id') +newNum);
    $('#cus_title').text("Customer 0"+newNum);
});
});
```

this bit

```
$('#cus_title').text("Customer 0"+newNum);
```

is set to integer the title so it goes "Customer 01, Customer 02, Customer 03" etc. etc.  it works, but not in the manner intended.  What happens is the first title updates and the duplicates follow.

For example, if I duplicate it 7 times, from the top of the Page down the titles go "Customer 07, Customer 01, Customer 02, Customer 03, Customer 04, Customer 05, Customer 06" rather than just staying in order.

How can I get it to clone in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [prepending](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) the clone to the parent

```
$("#p20_01_yes").click(function(){
var num = $('.clone_el').length,
newNum = new Number(num + 1),
clonedFieldset = $("#cloner").clone().prependTo("#page20"); // <- here

clonedFieldset.attr('id',('cloner')+newNum).find("input, textarea, select, label, #cus_title").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);

    item.attr('name', item.attr('name') +newNum).attr('id', item.attr('id') +newNum);
    $('#cus_title').text("Customer 0"+newNum);
});
});
```

This reverses the order which I am guessing is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: YES!!! PERFECT!!! IT WORKS!!! and it even pushed the "add" button further down on the page... which I was going to make a post about later on because it just stayed in the same place, so this got two birds with one stone lol.  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No problem. You can mark this as top answer if it solved your issue altogether.

Comment: I gotta wait 3 more minutes before it allows me to, already tried lol.